# Is global axios interceptor possible in nextjs?

Tags: axios, next.js

I am trying to implement a global interceptor for logging response and request params.

Tried to implement this way: https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#interceptors

But it doesn't work. This worked on CRA. It doesn't work on nestjs (nodejs) framework too.

I was wondering if axios interceptor can't run on server ?

Comment: Can you add more details about what exactly you are trying to accomplish with interceptors?